# Rspec 3. undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ConfigsAPI::GETApiConfig:0x007f84d93fbb90>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

I want to test API controller with rspec.
So here is the simple piece of code:

```
require 'rails_helper'  
describe "GET /api/config" do

  it 'routes GET to /api/config to Api::V1::ConfigsController#show' do
    get '/api/config.json'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end

end
```

But I've got an error:

```
1) Configs API GET /api/config routes GET to /api/config to Api::V1::ConfigsController#show
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ConfigsAPI::GETApiConfig:0x007f84d93fbb90>
     # ./spec/routing/api/v1/devise/configs_routing_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: not sure but you can try to add `type` to the tests. For example `it 'routes GET ...', :type => :request do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RSpec 3` you would do:

```
get '/api/config.json'
expect(response.status).to be(200)
```

What you're missing is a type declaration in your describe block, ie:

```
describe "GET /api/config", type: :controller do
end
```

Comment: Who does it work? How is calling the method of undefined variable defined?

Comment: @Nakilon i'm not sure i understand what you're asking

Comment: In OP's question the problem was in the `undefined 'response'`. You still refer to this variable. How does appending another method call to it makes it `defined`?

Comment: Well this questions is 3 mos old - I think he edited it a few times as I answered.  In the end, we got it working

Comment: It was never edited ..( I just want to understand this Rspec Rails behavior.

Comment: Is it possible to put the code that worked up?  Whatever made "response" defined?

Answer (score 2):

Are your controller specs in the specs/controller directory? If not, then Rspec needs you to explicitly declare that they are controller specs by tagging the describe with the metadata `:type => :controller` This is because the `response` variable is available only when your spec is set up as a controller spec i.e

```
require 'rails_helper'  
describe "GET /api/config", type: :controller do

  it 'routes GET to /api/config to Api::V1::ConfigsController#show' do
    get '/api/config.json'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end

end
```

Also take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/alex-zige/5795358)

Comment: How to add the "response" variable to the "api" spec (vs controller), so all the 'how to test an api" examples out there can run?  Must be a specific library to include?  (include Rack::Test::Methods doesn't seem to do it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this syntax

> ```
> describe "GET /api/config", type: :controller do
>
>   it 'routes GET to /api/config to Api::V1::ConfigsController#show' do
>     get '/api/config.json'
>     expect(last_response.status).to be(200)
>   end
>
> end
> ```

Use `expect(last_response.status).to be(200)` instead of only **response**

It works for me!

FYI:
I am using rails 5