# How to examine the response of an API post in an RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Below is my rspec. Notice that three lines are commented out. This rspec passes.

```
describe "/my_api_endpoint" do
    it 'Blah Blah Blah' do
      post "/my_api_endpoint", @params
      # expect(response).to be_success
      # json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      # puts "json = #{json}"
      last_response.should be_ok
    end
end
```

However, not only do I need to know that the `POST` returned success, I also need to examine the JSON it returns. Somehow I cannot do this. When I comment those three lines back in, I get the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `response' for  <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_9:0x007f84c58c31f0>`
```

How do I examine the results of the `post`?

Comment: Have you added `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of this file?

Comment: Yes `require spec_helper` is at the top of this file.

Comment: What's your rspec version? If rspec3, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776069/rspec-3-undefined-local-variable-or-method-response-for-rspecexamplegroup) may help  you.

Comment: rspec version: 2.14.7

Answer (score 0):

My work colleague provided me this answer:

For Sinatra apps the response is in `last_response` not in `response`.